# fade in-out elements sequentially (on after another) css in loop

Tags: css

I want to fade in-out elements sequentially (one after another) with css only, ie show one, hide it, show next one, hide it and so on, then repeat. At the moment I have this css it works fine, but I will have 20 elements and it seems like a lot of code for something so simple. Any suggestions on how to improve this with less code?

```
  .map-presence__stat--stat1 {
      animation: fadeInOut1 6s ease-in-out;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

.map-presence__stat--stat2 {
  animation: fadeInOut2 6s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.map-presence__stat--stat3 {
  animation: fadeInOut3 6s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut1 {
  0%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  32%{
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  33%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut2 {
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  32%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  67%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


@-webkit-keyframes fadeInOut3 {
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  32%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  67%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want something like this - https://jsfiddle.net/vedjohd2/

Comment: @San sort of but only one showing at a time